# How can I read the value of an RxSwift property? <Driver>Bool

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'd like to read the value of a property

```
var checkInEnabled: Driver<Bool> { get }
```

I only need to to run a bit code once when the class has loaded, so I don't want to use something like:

```
roomStatus.checkInEnabled
      .drive { [weak self] enabled in
        if !enabled {
          // do something everytime it changes
        }
      }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But rather something like this:

```
if roomStatus.checkInEnabled {
//only do something now
}
```

### Thanks for reading,

Comment: As I understand it, the `Driver` is a sequence.  If nothing has been emitted by that sequence then it doesn't have a value to read.  It sounds like you are trying to do something that is fighting against the Reactive model.  Whatever you are trying to accomplish with your `if` check should be done in response to the `Driver` emitting a value.

Comment: @ScottThompson is correct. A `Driver` doesn't store state, it emits values. There is no Bool inside your driver to query.

Comment: If you explained better exactly what you are trying to do, it may help. Is `checkInEnabled` in the same class as the one where you want to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

use take(1) operator

```
roomStatus.checkInEnabled
      .take(1)
      .drive { [weak self] enabled in
        if !enabled {
           // ~~~
        }
      }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```